# Run a script that requires multiple arguments and uses ExitStack

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python3 script that requires three arguments: -orig, -corr, -out, where "orig" and "corr" are used to generate "out". "-orig" allows for only one file as argument, while "-corr" allows for multiple files as input. The script uses ExitStack for handling multiple files at the same time.

When I run the script in command line specifying the files for each argument:

```
python3 myscript.py -orig <orig_file> -cor <cor_file1> [<cor_file2> ...] -out <outputfile>
```

it works without problem, but **I would like to run the script over several "orig" files and the corresponding "corr" files. Any ideas?**

This is the start of the script:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
  in_files = [stack.enter_context(open(i)) for i in [args.orig]+args.cor]
# Process each line of all input files.
  for line_id, line in enumerate(zip(*in_files)):  
    orig_sent = line[0].strip()  
    cor_sents = line[1:]
```

And the section corresponding to the arguments:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# Define and parse program input
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="blabla",formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter, usage="%(prog)s [-h] [options] -orig ORIG -cor COR [COR ...] -out OUT")
  parser.add_argument("-orig", help="The path to the original text file.", required=True)
  parser.add_argument("-cor", help="The paths to >= 1 corrected text files.", nargs="+", default=[], required=True)
  parser.add_argument("-out", help="The output filepath.", required=True)
  args = parser.parse_args()
# Run the program.
  main(args)
```

Comment: `-orig` expects only one argument, and the shell expands `orig**` to multiple arguments *before* Python run. Python neither sees nor expands the glob.

Comment: The start of the script indicates that it can handle multiple files, but that's *one* file from `-orig` and the rest from `-cor`.

Comment: I see. What I would like is to run the script over a bunch of original files and their corresponding corrected versions. Any idea?

Comment: Is there a one-to-one relationship between original and corrected files, or a one-to-many (as is currently implied by your code)?

Comment: It is a one-to-many.

Comment: In that case, it's not clear how to extend your code to support multiple original files. How would you know which files specified by `-cor` are associated with each file specified by `-orig`? Right now, *all* files following `-cor` would go to the *first* file after `-orig`; which should go with the second, or third, etc.?